# How to save to Firebase - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Probably I get something wrong.

This is how I try to store user data after fb auth:

```
    func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError?) {
    print("sds")
    print(result)
    if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return
    }
    let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credentialWithAccessToken(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString)

    FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithCredential(credential) { (user, error) in

        if let email = user?.email
        {
           self.ref.child("users").child(user!.uid).setValue(["email": email])
        }
        if let photoURL = user?.photoURL?.absoluteString
        {
            self.ref.child("users").child(user!.uid).setValue(["photoURL": photoURL])
        }
    }}
```

What I get when I look into database in console is only the photoURL, looks like email is created and immmediately after deleted/overriden.

What's the correct way to save data to firebase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set value you are overwriting everything at that path.

If you only want to replace certain values you should use:

```
self.ref.child("users").child(user!.uid).child("photoURL").setValue(photoURL)
```

Or replace/create entire user object

```
self.ref.child("users").child(user!.uid).setValue(["email": email, "photoURL": user?.photoURL?.absoluteString ?? ""])
```

Comment: this way I end up with `Command failed due to signal:segmentation fault 11` which is very annoying cause I get it often and it has no information what exactly is wrong

Comment: Set a break point and step though, are you sure the error is coming from that line?

Comment: this is not a runtime error, it occurs when I add the second if-let

Comment: well that sounds like a swift problem not a firebase problem

Comment: probably, but it occurs very often when using firebase, for instance when you instantiate ref FirDatabaseReference without a child etc

Comment: yup, nested if-let structure helped me get rid of this error. your part works well, thanks!